# Java function to output every case possible in a string

Tags: java, string, class, case

I am trying to make a function that outputs every case possible of a string. The function must output each variation of a string and keep a counter for that variation. For example in no particular order:

> C.d
>   C>d
>   C>D
>   C.D
>   c.d
>   c.D
>   c>D
>   c>d

So far I have this:

```
public int allCase(String data)
{
    int count=0; // counter for the amount of case changes completed
    int size= data.length();// length of incoming string
    char c[]= data.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    double maxpos=Math.pow(2,size);
  System.out.println("Maximum possibilities= "+maxpos);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {          
      if (c[i]> 33 &&  c[i]<64) // if the character is special characters !@#$%^&*()_<>?,./
      {                     // prints characters in front  and behind of special character
        System.out.println( data.substring(0,i)+((char)(c[i]+16))+data.substring(i+1));
      }
      else{
      // output the string variation

      }
        count++;                                                       
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: `.` and `>` are not the same character in different cases, they're distinct characters that happen to be on the same key of the keyboard.

Comment: the function is supposed to act like a <shift> key for a keyboard i suppose. I mainly need help just for the logic for the letters

Comment: There's no way that's going to work -- count will just end up == size.  For it to work to enumerate the possibilities you'd need to iterate maxpos times.

Comment: (Hint:  If you iterate `for(int i = 0; i < maxpos; i++)` then each `1` bit in `i` will correspond to an upper-shift character and each `0` bit (starting from bit 32-size) will correspond to a lower-shift character.)

Comment: (Don't forget to round `maxpos` when casting to `int`, though.)

Comment: Don't need to round `maxpos` when making it an `int`.  Provided it's within range for an `int`, there won't be a rounding error, because it's an exact power of two.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Only if `pow` is implemented to recognize the exact power of two case.  (Which it probably is, but why risk it?)

Comment: Hmm, interesting point.  Yes, you are right, I am wrong, and I retract my earlier comment.  For myself, I would have avoided the issue completely by doing the "recursive" version that Mike Housky hinted at in his final sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the alphabetic characters as a group, adding or subtracting 32, but the rest of the mappings aren't regular enough to beat a table lookup.

Keep two parallel strings:

```
shifted   = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~!@#$%^&*()_+|<>?:\"{}";
unshifted = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`1234567890-=\,./;'[]";
```

Then, find each character in one or the other string with .indexOf().  Find the opposite shift at the same index in the other string.  If a character isn't in either string, then it's a space or another character that isn't part of a shifted/unshifted pair. The total number of strings to generate is then 2^(number of chars found in one of those strings).

Speaking of powers of 2, using Math.pow() is a lousy way to compute small powers of 2.  Use `1L<<n` instead of Math.pow(n) for integers `0 <= n <= 62`, or even `1<<n` for `0<=n<=30` if you're able to live with only being able to print out a billion or so strings.

You can make an iterative version, looping from an index value of 0 to (2^n)-1, where n the length of the input string, and then loop for k=0 to (n-1) testing bit k of the outer loop index value to see whether to print upper or lowercase version of the character. *I didn't see it before, but Hot Licks has a comment about using this approach.*  To perform that test, observe that `index&(1<<k)` is nonzero if and only if bit k is set in (index).

A recursive version is much simpler, but I suspect you'll learn about that later.